# Exporting Pandas series as JSON - error with numpy types

Tags: python, json, numpy, pandas

I want to export some rows from a Pandas DataFrame to JSON.
However, when exporting a columns I got an error:

```
TypeError: False is not JSON serializable
```

or

```
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
```

I looked up in my data and the problem occurs for `numpy.int64` and `numpy.bool_` (`numpy.float64` works fine).

For example, the problem appears for the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import simplejson as json

df = pd.DataFrame([[False,0],[True,1]], columns=['a','b'])
json.dumps(df.ix[0].to_dict())
```

(The same thing happens for `dict(df.ix[0])`).

Is there a simple workaround to export Pandas Series to JSON?

Or at least, a function that coerce any numpy type to the closest type compatible with JSON?

Answer (score 7):

DataFrame has a method to export itself to `json` string:

```
>>> df.to_json()
'{"a":{"0":false,"1":true},"b":{"0":0,"1":1}}'
```

You can also export it directly to a file:

```
>>> df.to_json(filename)
```

Comment: It works with DataFrames, thanks. Does it work also with Series? I am getting `OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached`.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal It does work with `Series`. Can you post a `Series` object that reproduces the stack overflow?

Comment: @PhillipCloud For example the one in the question, i.e. `df.ix[0].to_json()` for `df = pd.DataFrame([[False,0],[True,1]], columns=['a','b'])`.

Comment: I get `'{"a":false,"b":0}'`, as expected. That's on pandas `git` master, which may have this fix in it (and not in the 0.12 release). Let me see.

Comment: @PhillipCloud Yup, it's a bug in 0.12, but it's fixed on master.